# How do i append text to a file after checking if the text is not already available in the file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to scripting with bash, and I am trying to make a user friendly script to download videos using youtube-dl.
After getting the available streams from a video link, i want to write to a file the available resolutions for the given video. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05X0RRmUtE0 > info.txt
filename='info.txt'
echo Start
cat > res.txt
echo "" > res.txt
while read p; do 
    for i in '240p' '360p' '480p' '720p' '1080p' '2160p'; do
        while read q; do
            if [[$i == $q]]; then 
                break
            else
                echo $i >> res.txt
            fi
        done < res.txt
    done
done < $filename
```

With the current script, '240p' endlessly gets appended to 'res.txt'. I am not able to figure out where i am going wrong

UPDATE

i have edited the code as follows:

`while read p ; do
    for i in '240p' '360p'  '480p' '720p' '1080p' '2160p' ; do
        if [[ "$p" == *"$i"* ]]; then
            while read q; do
                if [[ "$q" == "$i" ]]; then
                    break
                else
                    echo $i >> res.txt
                fi
            done < res.txt

        fi
    done
done < info.txt`

but i still do not get the ouput I want
also, for those who do not understand what the script is supposed to do:

1) input a link and extract the available streams to a text file ( `youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05X0RRmUtE0 > info.txt`)

2) append recurring resolutions from the streams in info.txt to another file res.txt only once

Comment: You read "p" ("while read p; do") but then you don't use it. Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll ignore the outer loop (`read p ... < $filename`) since it does not impact the issue you're asking about, but you should probably check why it's there because it doesn't do anything right now.

The first inner loop (`for i in '240p' '360p' ...`) loops over that list, and performs the second inner loop for every value.

The second inner loop (`read q ... < res.txt`) reads res.txt, and compares every line to the value from the first inner loop. If the values match, the second inner loop stops, and the first inner loop continues with the next value, restarting the second inner loop at the beginning of the file.

If the values do not match, you add '240p' to the res.txt file. If it never finds a matching value, it will keep going endlessly, because **it does not simply use the original contents of the file, it also reads lines added to this file during the process.**

This means that, if the res.txt file does not contain one of the values of the first inner loop, it will get stuck at that value, and keep adding '240p' endlessly, except if the original file does not contain '240p', in which case it will read the entire file, adding a '240p' line for every value it already contains, then `break` when it encounters the first '240p' it added.

The only way this code will not get stuck is if res.txt contains all of the values from the first inner loop, or all except '240p' (which it will add, then finish).

EDIT:
As for a solution, I'd throw out the entire inner `while` loop, replacing it with `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05X0RRmUtE0 > info.txt
echo Start

rm res.txt >/dev/null 2>&1 # remove res.txt if it exists, don't care about warnings if it doesn't exist
touch res.txt # create empty file

while read p ; do
    for i in '240p' '360p'  '480p' '720p' '1080p' '2160p' ; do
        if [[ "$p" =~ "$i" ]]; then # regex matching ensures foo480pbar matches '480p'
            if ! grep "$p" res.txt >/dev/null 2>&1; then # if grep fails, res.txt does not contain $p yet
                echo $i >> res.txt
            fi
        fi
    done
done < info.txt
```

You could even throw out the `for` loop and put all the resolutions in one regex match, and combine both `if` statements into one, but this way it's easier to read what's going on, so I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader

Comment: this is what i want my script to do :    1) input a link and extract the available streams to a text file ( `youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05X0RRmUtE0 > info.txt`)          2) append recurring resolutions from the streams in info.txt to another file res.txt **only once**

Comment: Ah, I see. You need to move the `echo $i >> res.txt` out of the while loop, because in both versions it adds the missing resolution once for every non-matching resolution in that file, and the loop keeps reading the lines you're adding in that loop.

It's probably easier to just throw out the entire inner `while` loop. Have you considered `grep`? I'll update my answer with a suggestion in that direction.